# which Jquery version has resolved the ajax memory leak for IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, memory-leaks

Can any one please tell me which official version of jquery has resolved the bug 6242. I tried jquery 1.5, but the issue seems to be there still.

Comment: The bug is marked "fixed" for version 1.4.4.  You should post your code that you think is leaking.

Comment: Are you basically just asking a link to the bug 6242 page?

Answer (score 2):

[Bug #6242](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6242) is listed as fixed in 1.5 in this report: http://bugs.jquery.com/query?status=closed&resolution=fixed&milestone=1.5&report=203&order=priority and the bug itself is marked as fixed in 1.4.4.

You can look in the jQuery code you are using and see if it has this simple fix as described in the bug.  If it does, then your leak is likely for another reason.

Comment: // Stop memory leaks
    if ( s.async ) {
                                              try {
     xhr.onreadystatechange = null; 
     xhr.abort = null; 
                                              } catch(ex) {};
     xhr = null;
    }

Comment: This is the fix i see, but 1.5 Jquery has changed a lot, so not able to make out this fix. Can somebody help?

Comment: @user1096084 - Can somebody help with what?  What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: i am not able to find the above syntax like s.async in Jquery1.5 version which existed in 1.4.2 Jquery

Comment: @user1096084 - The fix was changed in form over time because the ajax code was reworked to work differently so it is not possible to track the specific change described in the bug in future versions.